Missing "appxrecipe" .Net Maui Won't Deploy
Description
I can't get around the following Deploy related error in Maui:
Error DEP1700: The recipe file "G:\QuickJournalSync\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\QuickJournalSync.build.appxrecipe" does not exist. You may need to build your project.

Missing appxrecipe
I'm trying to create a demo solution mixing .net maui (C# 8.0) with a Realm persistence example and a Syncfusion.
I've posted this in Github issues, too, for Maui, but am hoping someone in SO community can help me find a solution.
Neither realm nor Syncfusion are implicated here as this error has appeared off and on in Maui community and for me for about a half a year at least and nothing throws any errors. It's all about this weird "missing recipe" error.
In the past I've "fixed" by deleting bin, obj and vs folders in the project, manually, restarting windows and then builds would often work.
Not anymore. And now someone else was able to repo the error from the example project on github.
Steps to Reproduce
Use the repo here and let me know if you get the error like above.
Triage Failures
I have

deleted all bin obj and vs folders
cleaned solution
repaired visual studio

etc... I then completely uninstalled and installed visual studio. No change same result: can't debug app because it won't deploy because "missing recipe".
Similar issues from Past

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16975
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6398
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2493
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2447
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9467


Best of luck. I ran into this in a LOB app at work today. After upgrading to .Net 8, it refuses to run with this exact same error. And I can't downgrade to .Net 7, since that's been removed from my computer by IT since it's no longer supported. With no solution, I'm looking at re-writing in a different platform. I am giving up on MAUI indefinitely. I would advise everyone else do the same until the maintainers get their house in order.

Best of luck to you. I feel your pain but can't quite throw in towel.  There is a lot of 'brittle' right now in maui.

Hi all, additional information from the maui github issues version of this post: They claim I need to configure the Packaged or Not Packaged setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-unpackaged-cli?view=net-maui-8.0 . If anyone is able to get the sample repo working by changing the Packaged|Not Packaged setting, please share specific steps here. I'll "answer own" if I find the right fix. Thanks

Solved thanks to a Github Dotnet community member! see original maui issues thread
ANSWER: When confronted with "missing appxrecipe" check the WindowsPacakgeType attribute in the csproj file for the Maui app.
By commenting out the specifier, the project deploy failure is resolved!
To understand how to add the property back in, read about "pacakged versus unpackaged windows apps"
None-->
REMEBER: "Error DEP1700: The recipe file..." likely means a malformed WindowsPackageType specificer. Value cannot be "None".
Hope this helps someone :)

Doesn't work for me.

Can I ask, did you comment out the element from the project config file altogether, or did try and set a valid?
